# How to dissect a file path and keep extension Matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have my file path in a string :

```
path = 'D:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\capella_to_matlab.txt'
```

How can i put only the extension in an other string (Not just for this file but for any file i put in path variable) for example :

```
extension = '.txt'
```

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fileparts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) :

```
>> path = 'D:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\capella_to_matlab.txt';
>> [~,~,ext] = fileparts(path);
>> ext
ext =

    '.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks you  mery much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Path](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/87552-path) class:

```
>> path = Path("D:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\capella_to_matlab.txt")
>> path.extension

  ".txt"
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.